# Boolean modifier (difference) not staying with part

Tags: modifiers

Hello I'm new to Blender and the community.
I created a cube then another cube inside and used Boolean + Difference and it works great.
However when I go to move the main part with the cube modifier the modifier doesn't move with the main part.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to options:

1. You can **parent the cubes**. Select the child cube first, then the parent cube last. The parent is the one with the boolean modifier. (Selection color should be orange, the child's selection color should be red. Then you have the correct order.). The press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select *Object* to parent them. With <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> you can clear the parent relationship again.

**Note**: In the outliner, the child cube will be attached to the parent cube. You need to expand the hierarchy nodes to see and select the child cube. If you move a cube to another collection, the other cube will not be moved automatically but must be moved manually to the new collection.

2. Or you can **apply the *Boolean* modifier** in the modifier's tab. Then the changes of the mesh become permanent (destructive). The apply button is hidden in the drop-down menu for the modifier in Blender 2.9, it's right next to the modifier's name.

Comment: Thank You soo much.

Comment: @Del You're welcome!